# SMTP Traffic on port 25

Tags: php, smtp, port, network-traffic

What are the dangers of opening port 25 to allow smtp traffic through? I have a windows server 2003 box which has port 25 blocked (Not by ISP), I know ISP's for usually block this port from use but as I need it for some php scripts I'm running that notify users by email, Is there any dangers or precautionary actions I should take?

Any advice would be appreciated,

Thanks Luke.

Comment: Offtopic, not a programming question.

Comment: It is for security of a php script so yeah.

Comment: kinda disagree, he is going to be using php to automate something and was simply asking what the ramifications were in facilitating that programming task.

Comment: Could this down vote be corrected as I am trying to build a reputation on here and I asked a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking of unblocking port 25 on outbound traffic then no, not really.  If you are wanting unblock port 25 on incomming traffic to receive email from external scripts into your internal mail server then you need to ensure you have the mail server configured to prevent relaying etc.

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what I needed. Don't really know why I got a down vote but you told me exactly what I needed.